# If the def train of openai gym's cartpole is executed, it slows down the progress of the episode

Tags: openai-api

I am studying reinforcement learning. When agent.train() is executed when the code below is executed, the progress of the episode slows down.

RL algorithm is DQN. and using PER

```
for i in range(EPISODES):
    score = 0 # Total Sum Reward
    state, state_info = env.reset(seed=seed)
    # state = np.reshape(state, [1, state_size])
    state = torch.tensor(state, dtype=torch.float32).unsqueeze(0)
    done = False

    for t in count():
        # while not done:
        action = agent.select_action(state)
        next_state, reward, done, _, info = env.step(action)
        reward = reward if not done else -10
        score += reward
        
        # next_state = np.reshape(next_state, [1, state_size])
        next_state = torch.tensor(next_state, dtype=torch.float32, device=agent.device).unsqueeze(0)
        
        agent.memorize(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
        state = next_state

        # Get loss    
        time_q = time.time()    
        if agent.memory.tree.n_entries > 128:
            loss = agent.train()
            loss_lst.append([loss])
        time_w = time.time()
        print(f"time@@@{time_w - time_q}")
        
        agent.target_net_state_dict = agent.target_net.state_dict()
        agent.policy_net_state_dict = agent.policy_net.state_dict()

        for key in agent.policy_net_state_dict:
            agent.target_net_state_dict[key] = agent.policy_net_state_dict[key]*TAU + agent.target_net_state_dict[key]*(1-TAU)

        agent.target_net.load_state_dict(agent.target_net_state_dict)
        if done:
            break

    scores.append([score])
    avg_score = np.mean(scores[-100:])
    print(f"Episode : {i}  |  Episode Return : {score}  |  Return mean : {avg_score}")
```

```
    def train(self):
        batch, idxs, is_weight = self.memory.sample(self.batch_size)
        for i in range(self.batch_size):

            time_a = time.time()

            state, action, reward, next_state, done = batch[i]

            state = torch.tensor(state, device=self.device, dtype=torch.float32)
            action = torch.tensor(action, device=self.device, dtype=torch.int8)
            reward = torch.tensor(reward, device=self.device, dtype=torch.float32)
            next_state = torch.tensor(next_state, device=self.device, dtype=torch.float32)
            done = torch.tensor(done, device=self.device, dtype=torch.bool)
            
            if not done:
                target = torch.tensor(reward + self.gamma * torch.max(self.target_net.forward(next_state).to(self.device)).item(), dtype=torch.float32)
            else:
                target = torch.tensor(reward, device=self.device, dtype=torch.float32)

            time_c = time.time()
            print(f"c : {time_c - time_b}")

            target_f = self.target_net.forward(state).to(self.device)
            target_f[0, action] = target.item()

            time_d = time.time()
            print(f"d : {time_d - time_c}")

            loss = F.mse_loss(self.policy_net.forward(state).to(self.device), target_f)
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            self.optimizer.step()

            self.memory.update(idxs[i], loss.item())

            loss = torch.tensor(loss.cpu().data.numpy(), dtype=torch.float32).to(self.device)

        return loss
```

Does the cuda not work on def train? The graphics card seems to be working hard.

Is it possible to be slow because there are so many for loop?

I don't know where and how to fix it.

The cuda doesn't seem to work, so I added to.(self.device).